# Team Foundation Server creates too many connections with TFS Database(SQL Server)

Tags: java, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am using Java API & TFS SDK to query changeset information from TFS Server. Recently I found out that there are too many(>800) connections open (lying idle) to TFS Database from TFS Server. I am not directly interacting with the TFS Server Database but I am using TFS SDK API to connect to TFS Server.

Can it be a connection lean problem from TFS SDK? I am using VersionControlClient & WorkItemClient and all these connections I am closing when an API call is done.

What am I missing here? Why there are too many connections from TFS Server to TFS Server Database(SQL Server Database)? Are there any other connections in TFS SDK API which I need to close?

Comment: How did you check the connections?

Comment: I was using this query to fetch all connections to SQL Server.

SELECT DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections, loginame as LoginName, hostname, hostprocess FROM sys.sysprocesses with (nolock) WHERE dbid > 0 GROUP BY dbid, loginame, hostname, hostprocess;

Comment: Apart from this, These API I am using from TFS SDK :

                                                                                                
 Changeset[] changesets = vcc .queryHistory(serverPath, LatestVersionSpec.INSTANCE, 0, RecursionType.FULL, null, new DateVersionSpec(startDate), new DateVersionSpec(endDate), Integer.MAX_VALUE, true, true, true, false);

Comment: vcc.queryBranchObjects(ItemIdentifier, RecursionType.FULL);                    
  IdentityManagementService.readIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.ACCOUNT_NAME, userName, MembershipQuery.DIRECT,ReadIdentityOptions.NONE);
                                             
 vcc.getChangesForChangeset(changesetId, true, Integer.MAX_VALUE, null, null, true);

Comment: There are the API I am using . Not sure, if any one of these can cause connection leak.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the following query to check the number of connections for each database, and see which one has the most connections:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
       COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections, 
       loginame as LoginName 
FROM sys.sysprocesses 
WHERE dbid > 0 
GROUP BY dbid, loginame
```

You can use the [sp_who](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) stored procedure to list all current processes.

```
USE master;  
GO  
EXEC sp_who;  
GO
```

Comment: yes, I used the following query to check no. of connections:   SELECT DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, COUNT(dbid) as number of connections, loginame as LoginName, hostname, hostprocess FROM sys.sysprocesses with (nolock) WHERE dbid > 0 GROUP BY dbid, loginame, hostname, hostprocess;

Comment: and I found out that one of the Collections database was having too many open connections. Not sure it's becaue of any connection leak in API I am using or it's an issue with the Team Foundation Server.